# How to require a password to close a window?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, passwords

I would like to protect a window from closing, so when the user attempts to do that, a password has to be entered in order to complete the action. There is no need for a username to be entered.

I know how to intercept the `QWidget::closeEvent`, as in this example:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText(tr("Do you want to close the window?"));
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::No);
    msgBox.setModal(true);
    int ret = msgBox.exec();
    if (ret == QMessageBox::Yes)
        event->accept();
    else
        event->ignore();
}
```

The problem is, that the example uses `QMessageBox`, which does not allow a text to be entered, hence it does not suit my needs.

How to modify the code in order to prompt for a password?

Comment: You can't use `QMessageBox`, it only supports yes/no/cancel etc. Look at `QInputDialog` and use `textEchoMode` to hide the password

Comment: It worked!! Thanks @YSC

Comment: @Minikornio, may I ask you to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Instead of `QMessageBox` use `QDialog` and shape it to your needs.

## Example

Here is an example I have prepared for you in order to demonstrate how the proposed solution could be implemented:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
    QDialog dialog(this);
    auto *layoutDialog = new QVBoxLayout(&dialog);
    auto *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(&dialog);
    auto *label = new QLabel(tr("Enter password to close the window:"), &dialog);

    lineEdit->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);

    layoutDialog->addWidget(label);
    layoutDialog->addWidget(lineEdit);
    layoutDialog->addStretch();

    connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::editingFinished, [&]() {
        dialog.done(lineEdit->text() == "11223344");
    });

    dialog.resize(250, 100);

    if (dialog.exec())
        event->accept();
    else
        event->ignore();
}
```

**Note:** Of course you have to come up with a smarter way of how to keep the password safe.